# Listing separate table data from database using SQLite

Tags: javascript, database, html, sqlite

I'm currently creating an app using HTML5 and javascript. I'm at the stage where I'm writing the assessment code, where by a teacher can check the progress of students. I'm creating a separate table for each student who registers on the fly (this won;t be a huge number per classroom). Now I need to print all data from each table on the same screen, at the moment I have it working so it prints the NAME of each table in my database, but I can't get any further:

```
var tableName = db.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name");

var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

while (tableName.isValidRow()) {

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var name = tableName.fieldByName('name');
tr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
tbl.appendChild(tr);
tableName.next();

}

}
```

I'm thinking I have to create another while loop inside the initial loop, but have tried that with no success.

Comment: Why are you creating a separate table for each student?  It's more typical to use the same table and simply include a student_id field in the table.  Assuming you're writing a testing app, if you include a student_id and an assessment_id, you could have any number of students and assessments in the same table.  They all have the same schema, correct?  Then you don't need to care about metadata.

Comment: Hmmm maybe that would be a good option, but there are quite a lot of different books/assessment rows ie. 18 books with 9 activities per book, PER student. would this still make your proposed schema work correctly?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing exactly what you're talking about (It'd be a separate question) but it *probably* could work.  In the very least you could use one table for all students in a given assessment.  Essentially, the fact that you're having to ask the DB what the schema is in order to find your data is an indication that your schema isn't generalized enough.  A well-designed schema should allow you to store all data of the same type in the same table.  That will allow you to actually aggregate your data in a sane manner.